# Unable to see [test] version of action

Tags: google-smart-home

we submitted our first version of the action and passed the certification + review, as expected the action got deployed to production and the test version was not visible anymore.

I started a new release in the alpha channel and added testes to the alpha tester group, all of our testers opted in.

But all of us are not able to see the [test] version of our action

Tried to rerelease multiple times in diffrent channels and adding testers.